# formatMoney function in Javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, numbers, format

I need a function which can transform the number 10000 to this number: 10.000.

So I tried the following:

```
function formatMoney(money){
    var value = money.toString();
    var l = value.length;
    var new_value = 0;
    new_value = new_value.toString();
    if(l > 3){
        var moneyarray = value.split('');
        var u = 0;
        for(i = l;i >= 0;i--){
            if(u > 3){
                u = 0;
                new_value = "."+new_value;
            }
            new_value = moneyarray[i]+new_value;
            u++;
        }
    }
    return new_value;
}
```

And then call this:

```
formatMoney("10000");
```

But the result is

> 10.000undefined0"

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You're assigning the index counter to the length of the string;

```
var l = value.length;
...
for(i = l;i >= 0;i--){
```

And the down count starts with the length-index, which isn't present since arrays are zero-based. Subtract beforehand instead;

```
for(i = l;i >= 0;--i){
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Disregard this, I wasn't paying enough attention to the question.

If all you're looking to do is take numbers that are 4 digits or greater and put a dot in three digits from the right, you could give this a shot:

```
function formatMoney(money) {
    var moneyString = money.toString();
    var moneyLength = moneyString.length;

    if(moneyLength < 4) {
        return 0;
    }

    var dotIndex = moneyLength - 3;
    return moneyString.substr(0, dotIndex) + "." + moneyString.substr(dotIndex);
}
```

Also, formatting your code in the post is good stuff. Indent it all by four spaces.

Comment: OP seems non-American, so they switch . and , in numbers.  eg 1 million is 1.000.000,00.

Comment: Ooh, that would make sense. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

```
function formatMoney(money){
    var value = money.toString();
    var l = value.length;
    var new_value = 0;
    new_value = new_value.toString();
    if(l > 3){
        var moneyarray = value.split('');
        for(var i = l-1;i >= 0;i--){
            if((l-i)%3 === 0){
                new_value = "."+new_value;
            }
            new_value = moneyarray[i]+new_value;
        }
    } else {
        new_value = value;
    }
    return new_value;
}
```

A couple of things:

1. You were counting down with the wrong index (you were starting at l, instead of l-1)
2. You were not handling any value less than 1000
3. You don't need to use a counter variable `u`, you can just use modulo math to keep track of threes.

Answer (score 0):

I cut off some parts:

```
function formatMoney(money) {
    var value = money.toString();
    var l = value.length;
    var new_value = "";
    if (l > 3) {
        var u = 0;
        for (i = l-1;i >= 0;i--) {
            if (u == 3) {
                u = 0;
                new_value = "." + new_value;
            }
            new_value = value[i]+new_value;
            u++;
        }
    }
    return new_value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
function money(m) {
  m = m.toString().split('');
  for (var i = m.length - 3; i > 0; i -= 3)
      m.splice(i,0,".");
 return m.join('');
}

 console.log(money(1000000)); // "1.000.000
```

See this [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/ezofob/1/edit)